# Why is dropout a good fit for ReLU units?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, dropout

I have read this before that dropout interacts well with ReLU and recently going through [SNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02515.pdf) i came acoss this again. to quote:

> Dropout ﬁts well to rectiﬁed linear units, since zero is in the low variance region and corresponds to the default value

Please explain what it means and why it makes sense